# Common filters, how to access related record?

Tags: web2py

I want to check for the records in places whether the auth_user is in the group which assigned to the site and not the place as children:

```
Sites = db.define_table("sites",
                        ..
                        Field("visible_for", db.auth_group,default=1,writable=True),
                       )

Places = db.define_table("places",
                        ..
                         Field("sited_in", db.sites),
                         Field("created_by", db.auth_user,default=auth.user_id,update=auth.user_id,writable=True),
                   
                         common_filter = lambda query: (db.places.created_by == auth.user.id or auth.has_membership(db.places.sited_in.visible_for)
                        )
```

What I am doing wrong, because the first part works but the second of common filter does not apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `common_filter` function must return a DAL query, and the following is not a query:

```
db.places.created_by == auth.user.id or auth.has_membership(db.places.sited_in.visible_for)
```

It is not a query because (a) it uses the Python keyword `or`, whereas DAL queries must instead use the `|` operator, and (b) `auth.has_membership` does not return a query but instead returns a boolean. Also, `db.places.sited_in.visible_for` is not valid (once you have selected a specific record from `db.places`, you can fetch the `visible_for` field of the associated site via `row.sited_in.visible_for`, but `db.places.sited_in` is simply a DAL `Field` object and does not have a `visible_for` attribute).

If you want to check for group membership, you must construct the appropriate query. One approach is to use a `belongs` query with a nested select, as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#belongs):

```
authorized_sites = db(
    db.sites.visible_for.belongs(auth.user_groups.keys()))._select(db.sites.id)

Places = db.define_table('places',
    ...,
    common_filter = lambda query: (db.places.created_by == auth.user.id) |
        db.places.sited_for.belongs(authorized_sites))
```

I believe you can also use the following shortcut for the nested select, simply passing the `db.sites` query directly to the `belongs` method:

```
Places = db.define_table('places',
    ...,
    common_filter = lambda query: (db.places.created_by == auth.user.id) |
        db.places.sited_for.belongs(
            db.sites.visible_for.belongs(auth.user_groups.keys())))
```

`auth.user_groups` is a dictionary of all the `auth_groups` of which the user is a member, with the group `id`'s as keys and the `role`'s as values (so `auth.user_groups.keys()` is the list of the user's group `id`'s). Note, `auth.user_groups` is determined only once at login and then stored in the session, so may not be up-to-date if the user's group memberships have changed since logging in. To ensure the most up-to-date data, you will instead have to query to get the user's current set of group memberships.

Comment: Perfect! I have just the problem the user is not properly load because I am using jwt but I will make a new question for this!