# Auth with JWT in web2py

Tags: jwt, web2py

I run with web2py a rest api in the controller and there my jwt and the token works. In the model I am using fields with default values but this fields are never filled automatically because auth.user is None. I tried to init it manually but it does not work.

Sites.py:

```
if auth.user is None:
    auth = Auth(db, jwt = {'secret_key':'..hnv', 'user_param':"email"})
    #auth.jwt()
    auth.basic()
    #auth.user.update()
```

I tried also to add the parameter in db.py but no success:

```
auth = Auth(db,jwt = {'secret_key':'...', 'user_param':"email"}, host_names=configuration.get('host.names'))
```

Does I expect too much or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth = Auth(db, jwt = {'secret_key':'...', 'user_param':"email"})
```

If you instatiate `Auth` as above (i.e., adding the JWT functionality), when a request with a JWT token comes in, `auth.user` is not immediately populated when the above line is executed. Rather, the token is only read and `auth.user` populated when the `@auth.allows_jwt()` decorator is executed (i.e., in the requested controller). This means that in your model files where you have your `DAL` table definitions, `auth.user` (and `auth.user_id` and `auth.user_groups`) will still be `None` during requests authorized via JWT, so you cannot directly use those values as field defaults.

As an alternative, you can instead specify a function as a field default, with the function returning the relevant `auth` property:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    ...,
    Field('created_by', default=lambda: auth.user_id))
```

The `lambda` function defined above will not be called when the table is defined, but only later when actually creating a record, which presumably will only happen in a controller that has been decorated with `@auth.allows_jwt()` (and therefore, `auth.user` will have been populated by that point).

Another option is to force `auth.user` to be populated in the model file by calling `auth.allows_jwt` there (it returns a decorator, but since we are not using it as a decorator, we must instead pass it a no-op function and then call the returned function):

```
auth = Auth(db, jwt = {'secret_key':'...', 'user_param':"email"})
if not auth.user:
    try:
        # If there is a token, this will populate `auth.user`, 
        # `auth.user_id`, and `auth.user_groups` from the token data.
        auth.allows_jwt()(lambda: None)()
    except:
        # An error means the token is absent, expired, or invalid.
        pass
```

Once the above has been executed, you can then use `auth.user` and `auth.user_id` to specify field defaults in model definitions.

Comment: Well might be nice when the JWT would be available like a normal login. As you might know I was asking because of another problem which you solved for me. My code works now with auth.user_group and not as auth.user.user_group. Are you sure that it is right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64355820/common-filters-how-to-access-related-record/64357465#64357465

Comment: Fixed references to auth.user.user_group in the previous question. Regarding this question, I updated the answer with an additional option to populate `auth.user` in the model file on JWT-authenticated requests.

Comment: That looks like a great solution, but it comes in conflict when there is no token isset yet and login function have to be called. But I will find a solution, with lambda currently it also works perfectly! Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Updated the code to avoid an error when there is no token (or it is expired).

Comment: Super perfect solution now! Many thanks for your support!